# How to serialize a foreign key relationship as key value pair django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize an relationship in DRF whereas I attempt to get the following output:

```
"statistics":[
   "Attacks":{
      "id":971,
      "home_value":3,
      "away_value":2,
      "value":5
   },
   "Corners":{
      "id":972,
      "home_value":0,
      "away_value":0,
      "value":0
   }
]
```

I wrote the following code for my serializer of this model:

```
class StatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Statistic
        fields = ['id', 'home_value', 'away_value', 'name', 'value']

    def to_representation(self, instance: Statistic):
        representation = {instance.name: {
            "id": instance.id, 
            "home_value": instance.home_value,
            "away_value": instance.away_value, 
            "value": instance.value
        }}

        return representation
```

Which gets me the following output:

```
"statistics":[
   {
      "Attacks":{
         "id":971,
         "home_value":3,
         "away_value":2,
         "value":5
      }
   },
   {
      "Corners":{
         "id":972,
         "home_value":0,
         "away_value":0,
         "value":0
      }
   }
]
```

Is there any way to get it as demonstrated in the first example using django rest framework?

Comment: You mean removing the leading curly brackets from all of the objects of the array?

Comment: @AkifHussain Yes exactly and replacing it by the the field Statistic.name making it a key value pair

Comment: Well, this is not how array of objects work. You can have multiple values against a single key but you have to make an array of values. Key-value pair, as you can see from the name it is a pair!

Comment: Can you add the lines of code making that `statistics` JSON data? Now I can't find that code so I can't answer.